# Next.js - Show 500 Error Page without conditionally returning the Error component in every page

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, next.js

Is there a less repetitive way of showing the 500 error page than sending the errorCode as prop to the page component and conditionally return the Error component in every page.

As suggested in the Next.js docs:

```
import Error from 'next/error'

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
  const errorCode = res.ok ? false : res.statusCode
  const json = await res.json()

  return {
    props: { errorCode, stars: json.stargazers_count },
  }
}

export default function Page({ errorCode, stars }) {
  if (errorCode) {
    return <Error statusCode={errorCode} />
  }

  return <div>Next stars: {stars}</div>
}
```

Can this be caught globally instead of repeating this on every page?

```
if (errorCode) {
    return <Error statusCode={errorCode} />
  }
```

Comment: You could move the check for `errorCode` to your custom `_app` to avoid repeating that on every page.